# TensorFlow Lite on Android shows the same predictions for different inputs

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I created a .tflite model with keras. 
I tested this model with python for different set of inputs (28x28x3) and it works fine -> shows different predictions depending on photo on the input. 
When I use it on Android, it shows the same prediction value for all photo inputs.

Does anybody knows how to resolve this issue?

**Python script**

```
image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
image = image.astype("float") / 255.0
image = img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)

# load the trained convolutional neural network
print("[INFO] loading network...")
model = load_model(args["model"])
```

**Android**

```
private fun convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap: Bitmap): ByteBuffer {
    val inputSize = 28
    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(2352 * 4)
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
    val intValues = IntArray(inputSize * inputSize)
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
    var pixel = 0
    for (i in 0 until inputSize) {
        for (j in 0 until inputSize) {
            val value = intValues[pixel++]
            byteBuffer.put(((value shr 16 and 0xFF) / 255.0f).toByte())
            byteBuffer.put(((value shr 8 and 0xFF) / 255.0f).toByte())
            byteBuffer.put(((value and 0xFF) / 255.0f).toByte())
        }
    }
    return byteBuffer
}

private fun getPrediction(bitmap: Bitmap) {
    tensorFlowModel?.let { tensorFlowModel ->
        val tflite = Interpreter(tensorFlowModel, Interpreter.Options())
        val inputData = convertBitmapToByteBuffer(bitmap)
        val labelProbArray: Array<FloatArray> = Array(1) { FloatArray(2) }
        tflite.run(inputData, labelProbArray)
        val prediction = (labelProbArray[0][0])
    }
}
```

Comment: It might not be a bug in the tflite model since you have tested it with python. You can check whether python and android have the same mapping between output vectors and predictions.

Comment: @HanWang Could you give me more hints? I pasted a snip of code which I use to test this model with python and android.

Comment: Does `labelProbArray` generate the same result as in Python?

Comment: @HanWang No, the result in python is always different. Only on Android the result is always the same, it means I receive two the same values: [0,49, 0,51].

Comment: How about the input `bitmap`? Have you validated it on android?

Comment: @HanWang Yes, it always different. Do you think that inputData can be always the same?

Comment: I mean if they are in the same range of values. `[0, 255]` or `[0, 1]`, etc.

Comment: @HanWang As I checked 'byteBuffers' always has only 0 values. When I convert every item (it means Byte -> toInt) -> it always get '0' value. So byteBuffers has size 9408 with only '0' values.

Comment: Then there is something wrong in converting the raw input (Arraylist or whatever) to byteBuffer.

Comment: @HanWang Do you think that I should convert the bitmap to Greyscale? Now I put the color image at the input, but this model was trained using LeNet which needs grayscale image to be properly used - but it should be done via dividing bytes by 255.0f as I think.

Comment: I am confused. How did you make it work with Python?

Comment: @HanWang I checked and I put the proper greyscale image to the input. So the pixels are correct. Every pixel is represented by 8 bits. Even those I received the same result. I don't understand why I need to allocate size of ByteBuffer 4 times greater than 2352.

Comment: Maybe because you quantified the tflite model with float32 instead of int8?

Comment: @HanWang It's good point but now as I see I trained a model with Batch Size = 32.

Comment: There should not be a batch size for the model's inference.

Comment: @HanWang When I set the Batch size to "1" instead of 32 it predicts model incorrectly. I assume that the batch size should be there.